# How to change or reverse the position of words in a String object in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Like for example : To Create a string object with string "Welcome to objective-C"
and then to Print the string in as "objective-C to Welcome"
This should work for any string. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: What have you already tried? A little bit of problem-solving thinking goes a long way.

Comment: I have tried many, one of them doing it with "substringFromIndex:index", but it will work for only specifics, but I want in general, like for any three words string. I am not able to figure out still :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Not the most efficient solution but does his work.

```
NSString *myString = @"This is a test";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
// myWords is now: [@"This", @"is", @"a", @"test"]
NSMutableArray *reversed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myWords count]];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myWords reverseObjectEnumerator];
for (id element in enumerator) {
    [reversed addObject:element];
}
NSString *reverseString = [reversed componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@", reverseString);
```

If you have any question let me know.

**Update**

You can try just a simple for cycle. Like this.

```
NSString *myString = @"This is a test";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableString* theString = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i=[myWords count]-1; i>=0;i--){
    [theString appendFormat:@"%@ ", [myWords objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, the problem is I am using a GNUStep Compiler right now, so I have no idea what is supported and what is not. That for-loop is showing up errors, I think the Compiler does not support NSEnumerator :(

Comment: @dombsez: Thanks a ton!! It is working fine and exactly as I wanted. :)

Comment: By the way, Can this be done without using the componentsSeperatedByString:method??

Comment: This fails to separate words on new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, I think you should read a string till you encounter a space and store it in array and then use- `(void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myStr = @"India is my Country";

NSArray* array= [myStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" " ];
NSArray* reversedArray = [[array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",reversedArray);

NSString * result = [reversedArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```